# react-native ios build error, SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ KakaoSDKAuth (in target 'KakaoSDKAuth' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, react-native, build, cocoapods, yarnpkg

This is React Native app that contains android and ios. I can run android simulator just fine, but the problem is when trying to run and build ios simulator. I installed all the necessary packages by running this command `pod install` at `/ios` directory. This Macbook chip is `M1`. I have been trying many different ways to fix it for hours, but couldn't find a solution. Thank you.

Then the error is below:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: "dependencies" has dependency "react-dom" with range "17.0.1" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^17.0.2"
warning package.json: "dependencies" has dependency "react-native-web" with range "0.17.1" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^0.16.3"
$ react-native run-ios
info Launching iPhone 12 (iOS 16.0)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace PolicyholderApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme PolicyholderApp -destination id=C35CD837-FCAB-4B39-BA3C-B52F65AF113D")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening PolicyholderApp.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace PolicyholderApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme PolicyholderApp -destination id=C35CD837-FCAB-4B39-BA3C-B52F65AF113D

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

Run pre-actions

SchemeAction Run\ Script /var/folders/6n/7yp6ql7s72j_l_47mk1r9sg80000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-0nKoVj.sh
    cd /var/folders/6n/7yp6ql7s72j_l_47mk1r9sg80000gn/T/
    export ACTION=build
    export ADDITIONAL_SDKS=
    export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
    export ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION=NO
...
```

continue... and at the end

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ KakaoSDKAuth (in target 'KakaoSDKAuth' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Podfile

```
...
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
    # Workaround `Cycle inside FBReactNativeSpec` error for react-native 0.64
    # Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-812543933
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

In Xcode, I tried to change its `Build System` to be `Legacy Build System`. Cleared all the files in `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory. Cleared `node_modules`, `/ios/Pods`, `/ios/Podfile.lock` and re-installed them. None of them worked.